# Zero major faults when mmap a large file in c

Tags: c, perf

I wrote a sample C program:

Program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include<time.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include<inttypes.h>
int main()
{       
    int fd;
    char *data;
    fd = open("file.txt", O_RDWR);  
    int pagesize = getpagesize();
    data = mmap((caddr_t)0, pagesize, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, pagesize); 
    srand(time(NULL));  
    while(1)
    {
        int r = ( rand() % 9999 ) + 1;
        char x = data[r];
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

I'm doing "mmap" for a large file in c (which has size of 11GiB). When I compile this program and try to check major page faults using perf I'm getting zero.

Perf command:

```
perf stat -e major-faults ./test
```

I have run this program for around 30 seconds and tried to kill, number of major page faults reported by perf is zero. Size of my physical memory is 8GiB.

Also if I use a very large random number in place of 9999 I'm getting a segmentation fault.

Can anyone please suggest me what am I doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd argument to `mmap` is supposed to be the size of the file you are opening (in this case, 11GB or whatever,,, you can `fseek` to the end or `fstat` to get the exact size), not the pagesize. Also, I think the third argument of `mmap` is supposed to match the `open` flags. You're just reading from the file, so I would change `O_RDWR` to `O_RDONLY`. It makes sense that if you're only `mmap`ing the pagesize into the file, you won't get a page fault. Furthermore, increasing the 9999 to a random large number probably tries to read above the pagesize, which could explain the segfault.  Finally, best to check the return from `open` against -1 and the return from `mmap` against `MAP_FAILED` before continuing.